# What is the correct architecture for a time series predicting LSTM neural network?

Tags: architecture, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, lstm

## Concerning the structure of a LSTM network

If I wanted to create LSTM network for solving time series predictions, how should I structure the hiddens layers of the neural network?

- A `LSTM memory block` would represent a  hidden layer and all the nodes in the layer would be represented by `cells`?
- Each hidden layer should consist of numerous `LSTM memory blocks`, and a collection of such blocks will form a layer?

---

## Graphical representation:

### Either in this manner:

[image: proposed solution 1]

### Or like this ?

[image: proposed solution 2]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After talking to some of the professors at my university, I finally got this sorted out.

> You should view a *LSTM block* as a single neuron in your network.

Thus this network would be regarded as a neural network with a single hidden layer with two neurons:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you'd need multiple LSTMs to form a layer (see [this paper](http://www.felixgers.de/papers/phd.pdf) for example) but you should probably ask this on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I've read that thesis, and quite a few others - though I've never entirely grasped the precise architecture needed. Since each block could feed out multiple outputs (through different cells) a block should be able to act as a `layer`. I am just not sure that the weights (and of course the `bias`) will be able to adjust the output value to a given target in a time! On the other hand, it would do the job as a normal feed forward network - I'm led to believe.